# animation with medal & ribbon at level finished

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i am new to cocos2d and iphone. i have implemented one simple animation using particle system. it works fine. now i want some more animation like , when my star animation(using particles) completes , i want one medal with ribbon falling down from top to bottom in my screen, i want it's movement just same like we release medal from our hand & hold the ribbon. .can we achieve this kind of action or rather say animation using cocos2d ... any kind of help or idea would be appreciated a lot . .

i have implemented something like this :

[image]

Comment: i am thinking about using some rope physics with my ribbon & attach b2box body with it , i welcome any other ideas on it .

Answer (score 1):

I think rope physics would work, but it seems a little too much to add physics just for that.

I would say that the best strategy would be to make an CCSprite animated with CCAnimation.

There is a tutorial for that in this site: http://getsetgames.com/2010/04/18/how-to-animate-sprites-in-cocos2d/

[edit]
Cocos2d introduction to Rope Simulations: [cocos2d-iphone.org/verlet-rope](http://cocos2d-iphone.org/verlet-rope)

Comment: i dont think , spritesheet animation could help in what i want to achieve, becuase i want ribbon & my medal effect just like they seems in real world .. means , assume : you holding medal with ribbon attach with it & after sometime you release it from your hand then it's falling down ... i want this kind of movement or say animation

Comment: With a good artist its very possible to "fake" this behavior in a sprite animation. But, if you really want to use rope physics here is the link to cocos2d introduction to Rope Simulations: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/verlet-rope/